# Parsing C enum/structure/union/arrays using -fdump-translation-unit of GCC

Tags: parsing, gcc, struct, enums, union

I am using the **-fdump-translation-unit** option of GCC to parse C enum/structure/union/arrays. Consider the below code

```
enum eDAY
{
    monday = 0,
    tuesday,
    wednesday
};

enum eDAY day = monday;
```

I can get all the members of the enumerator parsing the dump of GCC.

But if the below declaration was not present

```
enum eDAY day = monday;
```

GCC's dump doesn't have any information about the members of the enumerator. The same problem exists with structures/unions etc. How can I solve this problem. Is there some kind of optimization flag which I need to turn off so that GCC parses all the objects even if it is not used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-fdump-translation-unit is a CPP option. If the above code was present in a .cpp file or if we ran g++ on the above code snippet with the flag -fdump-translation-unit we will get information about everything in the code (Even if there is a variable which is not used).